# Filtering out array duplicates by under key element

Tags: php, arrays, filtering

I want to filter out duplicates from multidimensional arrays by the array key in the under category.

I have to arrays

```
// $selectedOffers
    Array 
    (
        [Category1] => Array 
        (
            [2424] => Array 
            (
                [node_name] => Name2424
            )
            [2525] => Array 
            (
                [node_name] => Name2525
            )
        )
        [Category2] => Array 
        (
            [2121] => Array 
            (
                [node_name] => Name2121
            )
            [2222] => Array 
            (
                [node_name] => Name2222
            )
        )
    )

// $myProducts    
    Array 
    (
        [Category1] => Array 
        (
            [2323] => Array 
            (
                [node_name] => Name2323
            )
            [2525] => Array 
            (
                [node_name] => Name2525
            )
        )
    )
```

For filtering them out I've used `array_diff_key($selectedOffers, $myProducts)`. The problem is that it is filtering by category and not by under element. So if $selectedOffers and $myProducts array has the same category but different values in it it will stil show the same category.

I was thinking looping trough categories and building new array, but was wondering if there was easier way of doing this.

Any tips and help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php


$data = 
[
    [
        1 => [],
        2 => []
    ],
    [
        3 => [],
        4 => []
    ]
];

$mine = 
[
    [
        2 => []
    ],
    [
        3 => [],
        5 => []
    ]
];


$ids = [];
foreach($mine as $outer)
    foreach($outer as $k => $v)
        $ids[] = $k;

$filter = function($k) use ($ids) {
    return false === array_search($k, $ids);
};

$filtered = array_map(function($v) use ($filter) {
    return array_filter($v, $filter, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
}, $data);

var_export($filtered);
```

Output:

```
array (
0 => 
array (
    1 => 
    array (
    ),
),
1 => 
array (
    4 => 
    array (
    ),
),
)
```

For Php 5.5 (looks as though you could skip using array_filter):

```
$ids      = array_flip($ids);
$filtered = array_map(function($v) use ($ids) {
    return array_diff_key($v, $ids);
}, $data);
```

Comment: I know i already accepted the answer, but is there any way of doing this in php 5.5 ? Very nicely written code by the way :)

Comment: Added alternative to array_filter, please check if it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks, just an off topic question, how do I learn to write so neat code as this one :))

Comment: Not sure what you mean by neat?